# how to add click listener for a switch in listview adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a listview with a adapter, the listview items are linarlayout with switches containing random numbers,  how can write a click listener for the switches?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.kattah.myapplication;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    myadapter adp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> RandomNumbberList = new ArrayList<>();
        int i;
        i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            HashMap<String, String> RandomElement = new HashMap<>();
            int rnd = new Random().nextInt(100000);
            String num = String.valueOf(rnd);
            RandomElement.put("number", num);
            RandomNumbberList.add(RandomElement);
            i = i + 1;
        }
        ArrayList<String> items;
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        String currentrow;
        for (int u = 0; u < RandomNumbberList.size(); u++) {
            currentrow = RandomNumbberList.get(u).toString();
            items.add(currentrow);
        }
        lv = findViewById(R.id.lster);
        adp = new myadapter(this, R.layout.list_row2, items, lv);
        lv.setAdapter(adp);
    }
}
```

list_row2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:padding="5dip">
        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Switch"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

myadapter.java

```
package com.kattah.myapplication;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * Created by Vikram Diwakar on 1/23/2018.
 */
public class myadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    //the list values in the List of type hero
    List<String> items;
    //activity context
    Context context;
    //the layout resource file for the list items
    int resource;
    ListView lsst;
    //constructor initializing the values
    public myadapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> items, ListView lss) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.items = items;
        lsst = lss;
    }
    //this will return the ListView Item as a View
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //we need to get the view of the xml for our list item
        //And for this we need a layoutinflater
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        //getting the view
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null, false);
        Switch sw = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        // Get the text from the list and split it to get the random number
        String s = items.get(position);
        s = s.replace("{", "");
        s = s.replace("}", "");
        String str[] = s.split(",");
        String s1[] = str[0].split("=");
        sw.setText(s1[1]);
        sw.setTag(position);
        sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked == true) {
                    TerminalAdapter adpr = (TerminalAdapter) lsst.getAdapter();
                    final int firstListItemPosition = lsst.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + lsst.getChildCount() - 1;
                    for (int i = firstListItemPosition; i <= lastListItemPosition; i++) {

                        LinearLayout ln;
                        ln = (LinearLayout) getViewByPosition(i, lsst);
                        Switch swth;
                        swth = (Switch) ln.getChildAt(0);

                        if (swth != buttonView) {
                            swth.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        ;

                    }
                }
        });
        return view;
    }
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
        final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

        if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition) {
            return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
        } else {
            final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
            return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know where to put the code and how to access all the switches in the listview.

Comment: You already have code to respond to the `onCheckedChanged()` callback in your adapter. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: cannot reach to the switch buttons.

Comment: Sorry, the problem wasn't clear, I have edited the post. my problem is to make all the switches  off when choosing one switch and making it on. How to reach to the rest of the switches??

Comment: The data is in the adapter (in `items`). In the adapter you have access to those.

Comment: Now I edited the post again, I added a public View getViewByPosition in the adapter, which can get the view by its poition and I tried to check all the switches to make them off. When the selected switch is on, also does not work.

Comment: thanks, it is now working!

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but you need to understand that there is not one `View` per item. `ListView` recycles/reuses the `View`s and if you have 100 items there will not be 100 `View`s. It only creates as many `View`s as will fit on screen and then reuses them as the user scrolls.

Comment: The problem was accessing the rest of the menu switches to make them off..

Comment: as I said before, you need to change the DATA and not the VIEWs. Your approach is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the last edit! check the complete code above.